# Can checking additional congruencies be done for the strong version of Lucas test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Relating to how the Lucas sequence can be used to check if a number is prime or not, I've red various "additional congruence conditions" that must hold true if the number is prime. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime#Checking_additional_congruence_conditions) states

> there are additional congruence conditions we can check that have almost no additional computational cost

Take for example the additional check $V_{n+1} \equiv 2Q (\mod{n})$

For the strong version of the Lucas test, this certainly is not "at no additional cost" ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_pseudoprime#Strong_Lucas_pseudoprimes)). It does not calculate up to the $n+1$ term. Are these additional congruency checks only for the normal (aka weak) version of the Lucas test which does go up to $n+1$? Does it make sense to check additional congruencies when using the strong form of the test or would it not make a difference?

Another example from the article is

> Recall that $Q^{n + 1}$ is computed during the calculation of $U_{n + 1}$.

But $U_{n + 1}$ isn't computed for the strong version of the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the additional checks always carry *some* additional cost, whichever test you're doing - the question is how much.

The reason that they make sense to do here is that the additional cost is a lower-order term. Computing $V_{n+1}$ takes $O(\log n)$ arithmetic operations. Comparing it to $2Q$ modulo $n$ takes only $O(1)$ arithmetic operations. For large $n$, computing $V_{n+1}$, which we had to do anyway, takes the majority of the time.

It's true that if the strong Lucas test is used, then $V_{n+1}$ would not have been computed: we might have stopped at $V_{(n+1)/2}$, or $V_{(n+1)/4}$, or $V_{(n+1)/8}$, or something even smaller. However, this isn't a significant difference, because for most values of $n$ we could consider, the highest power of $2$ dividing $n+1$ isn't all that high. For instance, more than $99.9\%$ of the time, $n+1$ is not divisible by $2^{10} = 1024$, and so the strong Lucas test won't be more than $10$ steps away from getting to $V_{n+1}$.

If you're using the strong Lucas test, you can still do the extra checks by simply finishing the job and getting all the way to $V_{n+1}$ even though you didn't need it. True, this means that there is a greater additional cost to the extra checks - but in expectation, it's still an $O(1)$ cost compared to the $O(\log n)$ cost of doing the test to begin with.

Very rare inputs $n$ such as Mersenne numbers might be an exception to this rule, where the strong Lucas test might be very far away from computing $V_{n+1}$, and so the additional cost of an extra check is much worse.